# How to open window with diemensions

Tags: c++, window

I'm new to the OpenGl and the glew library and having trouble \displaying the the window title with dimensions. .

Comment: This code is not working, isn't it? The `glfwSetWindowTitle` method does only take 2 arguments.

Comment: Yes the code is not working with this i just don't know how to display the proper width and height within the title  implement i thought it would work like this

Comment: Then your question should be: "How do I format numbers in a string?"

Comment: oh but i am not using string you see what i want to do is display the dimension of the window within the title when the size of the window changes so the  width and height are updated within the title i am not sure if i can use string here

Comment: The second parameter has to be a `const char*`, which is a string. Maybe you should read up on C++ basics before trying to work with OpenGL?

Comment: @G_programmer24: The title of a window is a string. So you should learn how to format strings. Once you know how to do that it's as easy as prepare a string to used as window title (that's called formating) and then you can use that string for setting the window title.

Answer (score 2):

The `glfwSetWindowTitle` function expects only two parameters, where the second one has to be a null terminated string.

There are several ways how to get numbers into a string. You can, for example, use a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << "DBZ PARODY - " << width << ", " << height;
```

and then pass the constructed string to the window title

```
glfwSetWindowTitle(window,  sstr.str().c_str());
```

Comment: I am sorry this isn't what I am looking for the width and height stay the same when the window is resized I need them to update and display the current size of the window

Comment: @G_programmer24: Well, then I suggest you do that string formatting and window title setting whenever the window size changes. C++ is an *imperative* language, which means that you describe step-by-step what should happen and when it should happen. I'm under the impression that you're thinking in *declarative* terms, i.e. specification in general, broad terms how values fit together and whenever one piece changes the rest follows. *There are* programming languages like this, but C and C++ are not of that kind.

Comment: @G_programmer24 Seriously, do the basic tutorials before you delve into this. You'll struggle every step if you continue. Begin smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a callback to capture the resize event. Create a function (with the signature given below) to change your title every time you receive a resize event. Something like this:

```
void resize(GLFWwindow *win, int w, int h)
{
    std::string msg = "Title: " + std::to_string(w) + " " + std::to_string(h);
    glfwSetWindowTitle(win, msg.c_str());
}
```

and, at your main function, register this callback:

```
int main()
{
    (...)
    GLFWWindow *win;
    (...)
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(win, resize);
    (...)
}
```